# Find function-calls with all parameters

Tags: php, regex

I need to search (and replace) php files for the creation of an object, like:

```
$this->Add(new MyObject("Hello", "World"), ...);
```

This works so far with:

```
$pattern = '/new MyObject\((.*)\)/isU';
    preg_replace_callback($pattern,
        function($hit)
        {   // Replace
        },
        $file);
```

My problem is, that the parameters can contain brackets as well like:

```
$this->Add(MyObject("Hello (this is a bracket)", "World"), ...);
```

which makes the pattern detect only a part of the call:

```
new MyObject("Hello (this is a bracket)
```

instead of

```
MyObject("Hello (this is a bracket)", "World")
```

Is there a way to modify the pattern that it won't react on brackets inside single-quotes or double-quotes?

I tried something like:

```
$pattern = '/new MyObject\(".*?"(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|([^\)].*)\)/isU';
```

but that just finds all kind of things but not only the desired MyObjects.

Answer (score 1):

Using the flag `/U` makes quantifiers lazy, so that pattern `new MyObject\((.*)\)` will be interpreted as `new MyObject\((.*?)\)` making the closing `)` stop at the first occurrence.

What you might do is match `new MyObject` and then match balanced parenthesis recursing the first sub routine

```
new MyObject(\((?>[^()]+|(?1))*\))
```

**Explanation**

- `new MyObject` Match literally
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\(` Match `(`
  - `(?>[^()]+|(?1))*` Repeat 0+ times matching either any char except `(` and `)` or recurse the first capturing group
  - `\)` Match `)`
- `)` Close group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/K5bqj2/1)

To use parenthesis in side the single or double quotes:

```
\b(?:new\h+)?MyObject(\((?>[^()"']+|"(?:[^"\\]|\\.)*"|'(?:[^'\\]|\\.)*'|(?1))*\))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZR5eac/1)

Comment: Ah thanks,  that works fine so far! It assumes that every opening bracket ( has an corresponding closing bracket ), right? I have to check if thats always the case.

Comment: @Werner I see your point, I have added another pattern which will match from an opening till closing single or double quote

Comment: Your last regex does not match `$this->Add(MyObject("Hello (this is a bracket)", "World"), ...);`. BTW, this is not possible to make a decent and maintainable regex for such kind of task, it should be able to detect all possible type of tokens inside a function call. It might be used to match a specific subset, probably, or it needs a lot more work to make it work.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That feeling when you think you have it, and someone breaks your pattern ‍♂️This pattern will be the one that matches a specific subset :-)

Comment: The two lookbehinds are useless. Not very different, but I suggest https://regex101.com/r/DWCKIs/1 in particular to capture what is between the brackets.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I have removed the lookahead, good call. You could post that pattern to get the content between parenthesis.